How to find the intersection angle of a secant?
It is given a circle with radius R, intersected by the secant length L. It is known the distance B along a tangent line.
How can the angle X be calculated?
The given values are R,L,B
Thank you in advance!


The description and diagram is very confusing. Angle $a$ is definitely marked incorrectly, as that would mean $X=a/2$. What do you know about P? Is it given as coordinates, or some other way? What exactly are the inputs that we have in order calculate the output $X$?

Hi Jaap, sorry for the confusion. The given values are R,L,B.

I updated the question. L1=L2. But X can not be a/2, as this would only be correct if L2 would be symmetrically placed with point P on the circle. But P is not located on the cirlce. Sorry for the bad explanation, english is not my mother language. Is there more information needed? Thank you for the support anyway!

The vertical ray in the diagram is dependent on P, and is not a ray perpendicular to a side of the polygon. The angle $a$ is marked in the diagram as using that ray, which is incorrect.

Scaling it so $R=1$, and using Pythagoras on $L2$ I get $(B+\sin x)^2 + (1-\cos x)^2 = L^2$. This is tricky to solve for $x$, but Wolfram Alpha is able to do it.

Hi Jaap, thank you for patience. i updated the image again: The vertical Ray R1 is a quadrant line of the circle and considered as fix. If the angle x changes, Line L2 changes its position, resulting in Point P1 changing its position on line T, and change the value of B (or vice verca, chaging B, will change X). P1 slides along T, while P2 slides along the circle. For B = 0, P1 will touch the intersection point between T and the circle. For X = 0, P2 will touch the intersection point between T and the circle, but P1 will still remain on T. Again, thanks for your support!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The constraints: left point of $L$
is on the circle. The right point of line $L$ is on a tangential line.
If we use Cartesian coordinates where the origin is at the center of the circle
and where the horizontal tangent hits the circle at $x=0$,
the right point of $L$ has coordinates $(B,R)$.
The left point of $L$ is at $(-R\sin x,R\cos x)$.
The distance from that point to the right point of $L$ is by Pythagoras
$$
(B+R \sin x)^2+(R-R\cos x)^2=L^2 ;
$$
$$
(B/R+\sin x)^2+(1-\cos x)^2=(L/R)^2 ;
$$
Define $b\equiv B/R$, $l\equiv L/R$,
$$
(b+\sin x)^2+(1-\cos x)^2=l^2 ;
$$
$$
b^2+2b\sin x +2 -2 \cos x=l^2 ;
$$
$$
2b\sin x +2 -2 \cos x=l^2-b^2 ;
$$
$$
b\sin x +1 -\cos x=(l^2-b^2)/2 ;
$$
Define $b=c\sin \tau$ and $1=c\cos\tau$
such that $c\equiv \sqrt{b^2+1}$ and $\tan\tau \equiv  b$ are both also known.
$$
c \sin\tau \sin x +1 -c\cos\tau \cos x=(l^2-b^2)/2 ;
$$
$$
-c \cos(\tau+x) +1=(l^2-b^2)/2 ;
$$
$$
-c \cos(\tau+x)=(l^2-b^2)/2-1 ;
$$
$$
\cos(\tau+x)=\frac{1-(l^2-b^2)/2}{c} ;
$$
Then $x$ can be computed as
$$
x=\arccos \frac{1-(l^2-b^2)/2}{c}-\tau 
=\arccos \frac{1-(l^2-b^2)/2}{\sqrt{b^2+1}}-\arctan b
.
$$
A probably more elementary method is: by Pythagoras the origin, P2 and P1 are a right triangle,
so the distance from the origin to P1 is $\sqrt{R^2+B^2}=R\sqrt{1+b^2}$
and the angle P2-origin-P1 is $\arctan B/R=\arctan b$. The distance from the origin
to P4 is $R$. So the origin, P1 and P4 are a triangle with 3 sides of known length.
Denote the angle P4-origin-P1 as $\tau$. Then by the law of cosines in that triangle
$$
\cos\tau = \frac{R^2+\sqrt{R^2+B^2}^2-L^2}{2R\sqrt{R^2+B^2}}
= \frac{R^2+R^2+B^2-L^2}{2R\sqrt{R^2+B^2}}
= \frac{2+b^2-l^2}{2\sqrt{1+b^2}}
$$
and $x=\tau-\arctan b$ is the angle P4-origin-P2.

Hi Mathar, thank you for answer. Unfortunately i edited the question right in the time where you wrote your answer. Sorry for messing things up. Is it possible to edit the answer accorrding to the new sketch?

Done. This is of course just an extended version of what Scherphuis said.

Dear Mathar, Dear Scherphuis, thank you very much for good work and support. The given solution was proven using a 2D CAD model, so the answer can be defined as valid. Thanks again!
